# Power BI Deneb - how to increase white space between bars

Tags: powerbi, deneb

I am new to Deneb.
I start with the simple barchart and want to increase the space between the bars.
I've read a lot of documentations, search a lot, but cannot find anything. I am using Vega-Light.

Is it possible? How?

Answer (score 2):

Switch from the **Specification** tab to the **Config** tab in Deneb and add these lines to the `"bar": {},` section:

```
  "bar": {
    "discreteBandSize": {"band": 0.8},
    "continuousBandSize": {"band": 0.8}
  },
```

See https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/bar.html#config in the doc.

[image: Config settings]